# Как из экземпляров класса взять уникальные значения

Tags: c#, linq

Дан класс Lesson, представляющий урок:

```
public class Lesson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Lesson(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Также есть класс Student. У данного класса одно из свойств – это список всех уроков, которые он посещает:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }

    public Student(int age, string name, List<Lesson> lessons)
    {
        Age = age;
        Name = name;
        Lessons = lessons;
    }
}
```

Нужно реализовать метод GetUniqueLessonsCount, который принимает коллекцию студентов studens. Метод должен найти все уроки студентов старше 20 лет. А затем вернуть количество уникальных уроков.

Код для проверки:

```
static void Main()
{
    var students = new List<Student>
    {
        new Student(26, "Mark", new List<Lesson>
        {
            new Lesson("C# для продвинутых"),
            new Lesson("Linq2")
        }),
        new Student(20, "Alexey", new List<Lesson>
        {
            new Lesson("C++"),
            new Lesson("JavaScript")
        }),
        new Student(18, "Natasha", new List<Lesson>
        {
            new Lesson("SQL"),
            new Lesson("Python")
        }),

        new Student(19, "Elena", new List<Lesson>
        {
            new Lesson("C++"),
            new Lesson("PHP")
        }),

        new Student(21, "Joseph", new List<Lesson>
        {
            new Lesson("C# для продвинутых"),
            new Lesson("Linq"),
            new Lesson("Python"),
        })
    };
    var uniqueLessonsCount = GetUniqueLessonsCount(students);

    Console.WriteLine(uniqueLessonsCount);
}

Код выводит: 4
```

Я написал такой метод

```
 static int GetUniqueLessonsCount(IEnumerable<Student> students)
    {
        var b = students.Where(x => x.Age > 20).SelectMany(x => x.Lessons).Select(x => x.ToString());
       
        return b;
    }
```

Вытащил уроки, но не понимаю как из этих уроков вытащить уникальные уроки.
Когда использую Distinct

```
 var b = students.Where(x => x.Age > 20).SelectMany(x => x.Lessons).Distinct().Select(x=> x).Distinct().Count();
Выводит 5 - Должно быть 4 Что я делаю не так?
```

Comment: `Distinct` же https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-6.0

Comment: у меня он выводит 5 почему-то когда подсчитываю количество

Comment: @ДимаРейхц прочитайте всю страницу, там кроется ответ как нужно реализовать собственные типы данных чтобы `Distinct` работал правильно.

Comment: А, да, точно, нужно ещё `Lesson` чтобы умели между собой сравниваться, иначе `Distinct` не сработает правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Надо было просто сравнивать по имени курса и не парится, почему-то в голову не пришло.

```
static int GetUniqueLessonsCount(IEnumerable<Student> students)
        {
            var b = students.Where(x => x.Age > 20).SelectMany(x => x.Lessons);
            var d = b.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().Count();
            return d;
        }
```

Comment: Да, так будет работать, но лучше всё-таки описать в классе Lession компаратор, как вам написали

Answer (score 0):

```
static int GetUniqueLessonsCount(IEnumerable<Student> students)
{
    var lessons = students.Where(student => student.Age > 20).SelectMany(student => student.Lessons);

    var uniqueLessons = lessons.Distinct(new LessonIEqualityComparer());

    return uniqueLessons.Count();
}

class LessonIEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Lesson>
{
    public bool Equals(Lesson x, Lesson y)
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Lesson obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Мысль правильная, реализация - нет. 
`public class Lesson : IEqualityComparer<Lesson>
{
    public Lesson()
    {
    }
}`